# I get "Unable to find agent Filesystem" in my HA cluster with pcs

Tags: filesystems, high-availability, corosync

I am try to make a resource in my cluster, this line worked in others servers that i was configured in the pas.

```
sudo pcs cluster cib fs_cfg
sudo pcs -f fs_cfg resource create DrbdFS Filesystem device="/dev/drbd0" directory="/mnt/datos" fstype="ext4"
```

I get this error

```
Error: Unable to find agent 'Filesystem', try specifying its full name
```

Same error if I try to make this:

```
sudo pcs resource describe Filesystem
```

I guess some package is missing, buy i dont know.
lvm2 is install.

Thx to all,

Update:
The Filesystem resource should be listed here but it doesn't.

```
myname@myserver:/usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/heartbeat$ ls -l
total 136
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 38101 Jul 14  2022 IPaddr2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 25769 Jul 14  2022 LVM-activate
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 28123 Jul 14  2022 iSCSILogicalUnit
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 23595 Jul 14  2022 iSCSITarget
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13585 Jul 14  2022 iscsi
```

Comment: Fixed with `sudo apt-get install resource-agents`
The problem was install de minimized version of Ubuntu server 22.04.